# If condition doesn't enter for identical ints and break point displays an X

Tags: java, android, if-statement

[image: Screenshot of the code]

As you can see on the screenshot the values are the same but somehow the "return remark" part has an X and it's not executed.

The error when the x brake point is highlighted is:

```
Line 85 in LedgerManager.getRemarkForImageMap((com.paperless.transportation.services)  
No executable code found at line 85 in class com.paperless.transportation.services.LedgerManager
Suspend: thread
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean and Rebuild project, then debug.

Comment: This doesn't solve anything... I have done it a few times.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the compiled (and debugged) code doesn't exactly correlate to the source code.

You probably compiled/debugged it some time before then made changes and ran the debugger again without letting him know about the changes.

Rebuilding the project helps.

Comment: That's not the problem. I have rebuild it, clean the project a few times, re-open android studio, run the code on different devices. This is probably some android studio bug.